# JpaRepository loses column value on select

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a JpaRepository which has a method for searching by couple of entity fields. And it works good except one case. For some reason after obtaining entity - one column value is absent for specific row.

Help me please to find a reason.

**My JpaRepository code :**

```
public interface FinParameterRepository  extends JpaRepository<FinParameterOB, Long> {
    FinParameterOB findByFinancingIdAndIdx(Long financingId, Integer idx);
}
```

**My entity:**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "FINPARAMETER")
@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "SEKWENCJA", sequenceName = "GEN_FINPARAMETER_ID")
public class FinParameterOB {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEKWENCJA")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "IDX")
    private Integer    idx           = 0;
    @Column(name = "CAPTION", length = 50)
    private String     caption;
    @Column(name = "VALUEPAR")
    private BigDecimal valuepar;
    @Column(name = "FINANCINGID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long       financingId;
```

**Records in database:**

[image]

**Obtained results:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Enable sql logging using `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` and run the logged query it will help you out in debugging

Comment: you'll probably find that no select is executed for idx=1 because the entity is already loaded and modified with `valuepar=0`

Comment: @JensSchauder , thank you. Real reason was exactly as you said - entity was already modified and cached.